# SSD suddenly blank

Tags: windows-10, ssd, restore

I got a TRANCEND SSD with 128GB ( TS128GBSSD[XXX], I guess 3 years old ). Recently I used the computer running Windows 10 about 2 days ago. After I tried to start the computer yesterday i recognized, that there's absolutly no data on it.

TestDisk fails while looking for an boot record. The whole space is unallocated. I normaly turned the coputer down before the problem came up, so there was no blackout.

The only thing I did on the day before yesterday was changing some BIOS settings affecting the Wake on Lan functionaly.

I had pretty the same issue with the same SSD about one and a half year ago after a blackout. After creating a new partion and verifing that all sectors are ok I decided to reuse the drive again.

After a while of research I found out that some SSD controllers en- and decrypt the data on the flash-chip. Maybe it's possible that the controller lost his own hash to decrypt the files?

Does anyone of you had a similar issue and was able to restore some files?

Comment: "Maybe it's possible that the controller lost his own hash to decrypt the files?" - It's possible but the SSD wouldn't have encrypted the data without you specifically enabling it.

Comment: I didn't enabled that feature but thanks for your reply!